# jHipster 7.9 switches to testcontainers by default - how to revert back to old testing mechanism?

Tags: jhipster, bitbucket-pipelines, testcontainers

The jHipster 7.9 release uses testcontainers by default for running Java integration tests. This is causing problems with my existing bitbucket-pipeline.

Is there a way to switch back to the previous test running approach used by jHipster for integration tests?

Comment: Which dev Database did you select? Same as prod? Is h2 not an option for you?

Comment: What is your actual problem with using bitbucket-pipelines though? Do you have no Docker available? Besides, AFAIK you need to disable Ryuk on bitbucket-pipelines: https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#disabling-ryuk

Comment: @GaëlMarziou The jHipster .yo-rc.json setup for the Database was to use postgresql for dev and prod:
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",

Comment: After the jHipster 7.9 update I found that the bitbucket build was failing all of the spring `@IntegrationTests`.
I found the disabling-ryuk information, however, I still finding that the build "locked up". At that stage I thought it was easier to switch back to the old mechanism.

I eventually discovered that I could get the @IntegrationTests to work, after I switched the step to use the larger 2x memory option: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/#size

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a straightforward way to switch back to the old handling of postgresql databases as part of the build integration tests.

I instead kept with the newer testcontainers approach for postgresql Spring `@IntegrationTest` tests. I needed to disable ryuk, and I also needed to increase the bitbucket RAM for the step running the integration tests with the Bitbucket [2x feature](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/#size).

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: .... jhipster 7.9.2 based image ...

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 3000

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Clean & Build
        ....

    - step:
        name: Test and Verify
        size: 2x
        caches: ....
        services:
          - docker
        script:
          - export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true
          - ./mvnw -Pprod clean verify sonar:sonar

    ...
```